# Как исправить ошибку при сборке проекта Xcode?

Tags: sfml, xcode, macos, c++, компиляция

Работаю на Xcode 5.1.1 (MAC OS Mavericks) Для проекта подключил библиотеку `SFML`. Все includ'ы работают, все хорошо, но при сборке проекта Xcode выдает следующее:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "sf::String::String(char
>   const*, std::__1::locale const&)", referenced from: Game::Game() in
>   Game.o "Game::stageWindow", referenced from: Game::Game() in Game.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Исходный код :

main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "core/Game.h"

int main() {
    Game game;
}
```

Game.h

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Game {
public:
    Game();

    static void start();
    static void update();

    static sf::RenderWindow stageWindow;
};
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game() {
    stageWindow.create(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "UNTITLED");
}
void Game::start() {

}
void Game::update() {

}
```

Comment: Проверьте в Compile Source файл Game.cpp присутствует? Походу файлик либо не скомпилировался, либо не под ту архитектуру.

Comment: Файл компилируется, насчет архитектуры скорее всего. Но учитывая, что я перепробовал уже все варианты (в плане архитектуры), то я понятия не имею что делать

Comment: (Некрокомментарий) Скорее всего, вам нужно добавить опции для подключения SFML: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10491463/276994